# How to upgrade tensorflow from 1.3 to 1.4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I have tensorflow 1.3.0 installed in my computer (Ubuntu Mate 16.04, Python 2.7) and need to upgrade to 1.4.1 (CPU). I type the following in the terminal

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade \
  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

And everything seems okay. Then I go to python and type `tf.VERSION` and it outputs `1.3.0`. I've been trying with [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip), and also with and without the `-H` option. I also tried simply with `sudo pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow` but the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** When I run `sudo pip install --upgrade tensorflow` it says I already have tensorflow 1.4.1 installed (it uninstalls it and installs it again), but `pip list` says it's 1.3.0.

Comment: How many Python versions do you have? Is `pip` linked to which one? Btw, I suggest you to develop using virtual environments and this kind of problems wouldn't probably exist.

Comment: Why are you installing from googleapis? The latest on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/) is 1.4.1 as well. Try `python2.7 -m pip list`. Also `ls ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ | grep tensorflow`. Like nbro mentioned using virtualenvs would be the best solution for this problem.

Comment: I have 2.7 and 3. I explicitly installed the package in 2.7 with `sudo python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow` and now it works. I'll check virtual environments, thanks.